# invoke an autoit exe file in Selenium Ruby Webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, autoit

Please help guide me how to run an .exe file generated by AutoIT tool in a Selenium Ruby Webdriver script ?

My scenario is that I need to upload a file by clicking a Flash button, then select a file in the "Open" window popup. However, Selenium cannot interact with a window popup, so I used AutoIT tool to fill the file path and generated to a .exe file. The thing I want to do is that now I want Selenium will run the exe file generated by AutoIT tool after "Open" window popup displayed.

Comment: In java we have Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<pathtoexe>\\fileupload.exe " + args);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
f = IO.popen("path to your autoit exe")
puts f.readlines
```